# Appcenter build fails for xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

Xamarin.Forms project build successfully at my end but it fails building on Appcenter with the below errors :

```
Can not resolve reference: `System.Text.Encodings.Web`, referenced by `IdentityModel`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Text.Encodings.Web`, or remove the reference to `IdentityModel`. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/Myapp/MyApp.Android/MyApp.Android.csproj]
Can not resolve reference: `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`, referenced by `IdentityModel.OidcClient`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`, or remove the reference to `IdentityModel.OidcClient`. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyApp/MyApp.Android/MyApp.Android.csproj]
Can not resolve reference: `System.Collections.Immutable`, referenced by `Stripe.net`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Collections.Immutable`, or remove the reference to `Stripe.net`. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyApp/MyApp.Android/MyApp.Android.csproj]
```

Comment: have you tried the fixes suggested by the error messages?

Comment: @Jason I have reinstalled nugets and it has resoved it, actually both .config and .csproj have different version of packages

Comment: *"It has resolved it"* - if this means your problem is solved, then please *add an answer below* describing what solved your problem, so others know what the solution was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case both .config and .csproj have different version of packages, so I have reinstalled the nugets and it has resoved it.